# Why does debian not autocomplete all git commands?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, git, autocomplete

I am running debian

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I installed git, and tried to get git autocompletion. Reading long ago, I noticed I needed to install bash-completion.

I did this, and worked for a lot of autocompletion commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git bash-completion
```

However, there are still some git commands it does not autocomplete. i.e:

```
git stash list --name-only (Does not autocomplete --name-only)
```

Why is this? Can I fix it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked, the Git autocompletion contained in the `bash-completion` package offered fewer functions than the one that ships with Git itself.

I'd recommend to download a recent one, and source that:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Then add to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
[ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ] && . ~/.git-completion.bash
```

More info is available on [the Git website](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks).

Comment: I wonder if this has changed since 2018; nowadays, the `git` completion comes from the `git` package. See for yourself by checking with `dpkg -S /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`